# Grab URL's from text using grep

Tags: regex, url, grep

I wanted to use grep to show only the URL's in a text file.
I have tried to use:

```
grep "http://www\.[[:alpha:]]\.[[:alpha:]]"
```

I didn't get any results although there are URL's in the text file.

Also, how can i make it works for HTTPS also??

Thanks!

Comment: `-x` would match the lines that exactly match the specified regex.

Comment: I know, does not work without it either.

Comment: `"http://www\.[[:alpha:]]\+\.[[:alpha:]]\+"`?

Comment: Many site do not use `www` so solution that have this will fail for lots of site.

Comment: Many sites contain digits in the primary domain name. Consider changing the first `[[:alpha:]]` to `[[:alnum:]]` (note: it will *not* magically make it match *all* URLs; only more than now).

Comment: To match either "http" or "https" add `s?` after your `http`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `+` modifier here meaning the preceding item will be matched one or more times.

```
grep 'http://www\.[[:alpha:]]\+\.[[:alpha:]]\+' file
```